# Set background image for Index view only in Home controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing website for music school. I want to set a background image for sign in page only. How can I do that?

```
@Html.ActionLink("EntryMode","EntryMode","Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Students","Index","Students")

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form login-form" }))
{ ....
  //form code here


}
```

Comment: Sign in page using any layout?

Comment: No.the page uses _Layout.cshtml as layout

Comment: U can make a new layout specifically for ur sign in page..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a different background in a view, you have to make appropriate changes in the markup of that view, not in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. This can be made by simply wrapping the content of that page, for example, in a

```
<body style="background-image:url('background.png');">
</body>
```

tag, but it depends on the markup you already have.
Provide your code, it will help giving more certain answer.

**UPD** : 
Add this to the view

```
<style>
    body { background-image: url("background.jpg"); }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a layout page you could add the name of the controller as class on the body. That way you can do lots of controllerdriven layout manipulation. At least that's how i'd do it.

Something along the lines of this: (untested, edit at will)

```
<body class="controller-@ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Name">
 <div id="yourheaderimage">
  <img .../>
 </div>
</body>
```

combined with css

```
#yourheaderimage {
 display: none;
}

controller-HomeController #yourheaderimage {
 display: block;
}
```